# Pass PURGE requests to varnish via nginx

Tags: nginx, varnish

How can I configure nginx to pass a PURGE request from localhost to the Varnish backend?

Currently, the script causes this line to appear in the nginx logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2012:20:12:31 -0500] "PURGE /blog HTTP/1.1" 405 173 "-" "-"
```

Is there any way to rewrite this purge request to the Varnish backend (127.0.0.1:8080)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
error_page 418 = @purgepass;

location / {
    if ($request_method = PURGE ) {
        return 418;
    }
}

location @purgepass {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Not tested, but in theory it should work.

Based on http://blog.rogeriopvl.com/archives/nginx-and-the-http-options-method/

Comment: IIRC, you can't use `proxy_pass` in an if statement.

Comment: Fixed up so proxy_pass isn't directly used inside an if; used method recommended in the manual: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil#What_to_do_instead

Comment: Interesting approach. I can give it a try tomorrow and let you know :)